# .Net HttpWebRequest Get request return WebException

Tags: c#, .net, get, httpwebrequest

Try to create get request twice. However the second request always throw WebException with message: "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Here is the code spinet I used

```
public string Get(string url)
    {
        string strResult = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.UserAgent = this.UserAgent;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            strResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Todo
        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

and I am request to this [url](https://login.weixin.qq.com/jslogin?appid=wx782c26e4c19acffb&fun=new&lang=zh_CN&_=1491739754587)

If I start fiddler seems second request works as normal.
If I use HttpClient class it seems works as well.

Comment: [Help! Running Fiddler Fixes My App???](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) this post explain lots, as well as [Using HttpClient with SSL/TLS-based client side authentication](https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/using-httpclient-with-ssltls/)

Comment: change request.KeepAlive = true; fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Is there any lag between the requests when you start fiddler (do you hit a breakpoint in between). Perhaps add a quick `Thread.Sleep(250);` between your calls.

Another point to make, add some using statements that will close out the disposable classes.

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.UserAgent = this.UserAgent;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) { 
        strResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Had tried your code still throw an exception on the second request. However if i request google(www.google.com) end point it working fine.